# How to change selected item in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Hi I wrote that html codes and I want change selected item by using jQuery

```
<select id="slc"> 
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

I tried this but I can't change

```
$("#slc").val("2");

$("#slc").prop("selectedIndex", 1);
```

Comment: I am so sory, it was another problem. Thank you for your helps.

Answer (score 4):

```js
$("#slc option[value=3]").prop('selected', 'selected');//get option with value 3 and set selected
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="slc">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Do like this

Answer (score 1):

I think your first try was the right try.

```
 $('#slc').val('3');
```

It does seem to work:
https://jsfiddle.net/crix/hdtndzkb/

Did you include the jquery library right?
Does your code gets hit? Just try to see if it does by add a console.log() entry.

Answer (score 0):

When do you fire the code? Maybe you should just wrap it in a document.ready function?
I made this, and it works like a charm:
https://jsfiddle.net/41bna2e9/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#slc").val("2");
});
```

Hope that it helps!